# Database design for Wave-like collaboration system

Tags: database-design, full-text-search

How do we decide what the smallest unit is? For text collaboration should it be a word, a paragraph?

Is there going to be performance issues if the unit is too small? But it might be more flexible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the question is "wrong" and that this is not a relational model candidate.
A whole flow could be stored in a BLOB like storage/field, and you would use specialised (full-text) indexing. 
Maybe [this](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html) can help ?

Answer (score 1):

Implementing the multi-user interactive editing capabilities of Google Wave probably requires a unique data structure, not something that fits into a conventional relational database.

It all depends on your needs, of course.  Do you want to recover the full history of a document?  Or the order in which a user typed it?  How many users?  How many documents?  All of these things will impact the data model.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your goals are.

A "message" (one user to another) seems like a good unit.

You'd attach other stuff to that message, of course, like timestamp, session id, to-user, from-user -- whatever is necessary to reconstruct what actually happened.